# Why was https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305334/ migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration, mod-abuse

[MCP41010 Raspberry Pi Questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305334/) was wrongfully closed and migrated. The problem has nothing to do with the RPI and is 100% on-topic electronics question. This is mod abuse.

Comment: Half of the question is code for RPi.  The folks at RPi.SE are better at reading and understanding code for RPi.

Comment: You ignore the actual question, which is the digital pot controlling an LED. Which damaged the pot. Remove everything about the RPI and the question and answer stay the same.

Comment: Besides, code or mentioning RPI IS NOT A VALID CLOSE OR MIGRATION REASON!

Comment: Calling something "mod abuse" is out of line, and makes your question just a rant.

Comment: What about this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94479/digital-potentiometer-mcp4131-with-raspberry-pi  RaspberryPi in the title, includes code.... Mod abuse or inconsistent moderation, same difference

Comment: @jonrb that question is older than him becoming moderator and too old to migrate. But it would lilely have been blindly migrated.

Comment: @JonRB  Yes.  That question is old, and old questions can't be migrated.  It might even pre-date the dedicated Raspberry Pi stack.  If it were posted today, I would migrate it.  Notice also that the question had received only one answer, and it wasn't accepted.  RPi.SE would do better, I suspect.

Comment: I agree with @Passerby's statement (+1) and to some extent, Olin's answer. I think the Mod should have reworded the question to focus on root causes of issue. "Pot application/reliability problem" Since the OP didn't know what was relevant, the Moderator ought to have known what could be changed to make it so.

Answer (score 4):

Raspberry Pi was mentioned *right in the title*, and then there was code shown that of course is specific to RPi.

Perhaps after careful reading it might be possible to find that there is a basic electronics problem in there, but that would be more work than is expected of the volunteers here.  If your question really isn't about a Raspberry Pi or its code, then don't prominently feature them in the title and the question.